# Different cPanel physical memory usage with free -m and top terminal command

Tags: cpanel, linux, free, memory

So, I have a cPanel access. In the cPanel statistic, I see that my Physical Memory Usage is 2 GB and almost full.

[image: Physical Memory Usage in cPanel]

When I go to terminal and run `free -m` I got this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        257680     232988      24692      10514      26825     152897
-/+ buffers/cache:      53265     204415
Swap:         7811          0       7811
```

As we can see, the total physical memory is around 257 GB, then I assume maybe because it is the memory of the real computer (not only for my hosting server)

Then, I tried to run `top` command:

```
top - 16:37:43 up 118 days,  9:51,  3 users,  load average: 16.32, 15.80, 18.41
Tasks:   4 total,   1 running,   3 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 20.6%us,  7.4%sy,  1.1%ni, 70.2%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.5%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  263865228k total, 239103188k used, 24762040k free, 27469784k buffers
Swap:  7999484k total,        0k used,  7999484k free, 156720680k cached

    PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
 120795 linkjxsl  20   0  113m 1984  824 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 sshd              
 120865 linkjxsl  20   0  106m 1896 1520 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 bash              
 160395 linkjxsl  20   0  368m  21m  14m S  0.0  0.0   0:00.08 lsphp             
 169137 linkjxsl  20   0 15264 1036  844 R  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 top
```

And I got that. As we can see, the total memory is still around 263 GB.

But if I sum the virtual `VIRT`, it is around 600 MB only. The value here is not represents both the value in `free -m`, header on `top`, and even the cPanel statistic.

What am I missing here?

In addition here is the result when I run `cat /proc/meminfo`:

```
MemTotal:       263865228 kB
MemFree:        17284772 kB
Buffers:        27660140 kB
Cached:         164416712 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
MemCommitted:   2752512000 kB
VirtualSwap:           0 kB
Active:         129285076 kB
Inactive:       78478928 kB
Active(anon):   19536976 kB
Inactive(anon):  6643612 kB
Active(file):   109748100 kB
Inactive(file): 71835316 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       7999484 kB
SwapFree:        7999484 kB
Dirty:             23220 kB
Writeback:            12 kB
AnonPages:      15683704 kB
Mapped:          2369172 kB
Shmem:          10493380 kB
Slab:           37522684 kB
SReclaimable:   35520504 kB
SUnreclaim:      2002180 kB
KernelStack:       38160 kB
PageTables:       368772 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    139932096 kB
Committed_AS:   59309828 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:     1019032 kB
VmallocChunk:   34225288092 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        7168 kB
DirectMap2M:     2019328 kB
DirectMap1G:    266338304 kB
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is Cloudlinux cPanel the physical memory might be being taken up by the users disk cache as noted [here](https://docs.cloudlinux.com/index.html?memory_limits.html).

---

You can check your disk cache by doing the following where XXX is your user ID and looking for `Cached:` value.

`cat /proc/bc/XXX/meminfo`

To get your user id all you need to do is `id username` where 'username' is your username (eg `id root`, `id cpanelusername`, `id apache`, etc...) and this will give you a numerical ID to replace the XXX with.

[CloudLinux Docs Reference](https://docs.cloudlinux.com/index.html?memory_limits.html),  [ZenDesk KB Reference](https://cloudlinux.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004580905-Checking-personal-users-disk-cache-if-lveinfo-shows-memory-usage-but-no-processes-there-)

Comment: I can't find `bc` directory inside `/proc/`.. Though I'm not sure it is using `Cloudlinux cPanel`..